# 230. Kth Smallest Element in a BST

Tags: java

in c++ we can change the value of variable though pointers and references in another function but we cannot do it in java . Let me come back to the query

This is the problem description, Given the root of a binary search tree, and an integer k, return the kth smallest value (1-indexed) of all the values of the nodes in the tree.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        Integer cnt = 1, ans = 0;
        traverse(root, k , cnt, ans);
        return ans;
        
    }
    
    void traverse(TreeNode root, int k, Integer cnt, Integer ans){
        if(root == null) return;
        
        traverse(root.left, k, cnt, ans);
        if(cnt++ == k){
            ans = new Integer(root.val);
            return;
        }
        traverse(root.right, k, cnt, ans);

    }
}
```

Suppose I want to change the value of ans through traverse function which is void and does not return anything but wants to change the value of ans how can I do that?
As logic of program is not language-dependent there should be a way to it
the value of ans initially is zero and returning zero for any input

Comment: Why not just use the return value?

Comment: as traverse is recursive function and if i convert it into int method then return statements will cause problems

Comment: How so? It’s regular to have recursive functions return values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the logic is not language-dependent doesn't mean that the implementation is also not language-dependent. Imagine implementing the logic in a purely functional language that has no mutable state - the logic would be still the same, but the implementation needs to be very different.

To solve this problem your recursive function needs to update two values (`cnt` and `ans`) which makes the problem a bit unwieldy for the usual style (return the result directly).

Instead of that I would implement this with a helper object:

```
class Solution {
    public int kthSmallest(TreeNode root, int k) {
        Traverser t = new Traverser();
        t.traverse(root, k);
        return t.ans;
    }

    static class Traverser {
        int cnt = 1;
        int ans = 0;
        void traverse(TreeNode root, int k) {
            if (root == null) return;

            traverse(root.left, k);
            if (cnt++ == k) {
                ans = root.val;
                return;
            }
            traverse(root.right, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Traverser.traverse()` method neatly aligns with your `traverse` implementation - just the two parameters `ans` and `cnt` have been migrated into fields of the `Traverser` class.

Comment: problem solved thanks

Comment: @Suraj8363 if this solved your problem then you should mark it as the correct answer (there is a checkmark for it)